# How to test login with facebook and google api?

Tags: node.js, express, testing, chai

I am using **express** framework. And **chai** for testing. 

For local login, I have testing like pass data like {mobile_number, otp} and If the response is as described then test pass else fails. 
But now I don't know how should I test my login with facebook and google api. What's the good practice to do it. I have following endpoints

- GET :- /auth/facebook
- GET :- /auth/google

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to redirect through third party. It can be tested on localhost with UI which redirect to **third party**(fb, google). You can not test it by sending some raw data to your backend API.